# NHibernate exception with VS 2015 enterprise edition

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I get the following error when I try to configure NHibernate. I am using VS2015 enterprise edition, SQL server 2016 and NHibernate 3.3.3SP1 (I tried with the latest NHibernate but result is same) in windows 10 64 bit.  I believe it is related to System.Data.SqlServerCe (System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll). I copied that dll to the Required_Bins folder.

[image]

Comment: Did you try the steps like described here: http://sarkies.blogspot.be/2010/07/could-not-create-driver-from.html? (not the same as copy it to required_bins folder)

Comment: See also https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=973639. Read and follow strict. I think it will work then.

Comment: Yes, I tried that. Looks both posts point to the same information. I suspect, System.Data.SqlServerCe  is coming from older SQL server but I am trying with newest SQL server. Not sure does it fit?

Answer (score 1):

`SqlServerCeDriver` is not for accessing full blown SQL Server, [Sql Server Compact](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/) is another product. Your [configuration](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/session-configuration.html) is probably wrong, it should use `SqlClientDriver` instead.